# Запись экземпляров класса в файл: после перезапуска невозможно считать экземпляры

Tags: c++, файлы

Пробую записать экземпляры класса в файл через ofstream, потом считать через ifstream. 
Проблема:

- Записал экземпляр 1 в бинарный файл, сохранил. Потом второй и так далее. Считал данные с файла - всё работает как надо.
- Закрыл, снова запустил программу(консоль), выбрал пункт "Вывести все записи" -  НЕ работает... Или кракозябры на экране, или креш программы...3 часа ищу проблему, насколько понимаю проблема в том, что ПЛОХО сохранять класс в файл, нужно сериализацию делать, на это нет времени... Буду благодарен если кто сможет помочь в решении проблемы.

Видео (там есть отладочная информация, не обращайте на нее внимания, пожалуйста) - http://youtu.be/oZ-MvsdW0qA?hd=1

КЛАСС:

```
class UserList{
    char * _listName;
public:
    UserList();
    UserList(int);
    void SetListName(char *);
    void temp(); // @DEB
    void read(ifstream *in)  { in->read((char *) this, sizeof(UserList)); }
    void write(ofstream *out){ out->write((char *) this, sizeof(UserList)); }
};
```

ЗАПИСЬ В ФАЙЛ ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРА КЛАССА

```
void WriteToDB(UserList data, bool overwrite)
{
    ofstream out("AppData/DB_lists", ofstream::app);
    data.write(&out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    cout << "\n\nWRITTEN to DB\n";
    _getch();
    return;
}
```

ЧТЕНИЕ С ФАЙЛА

```
void ReadFromDB(char * pathtData, int counter)
{
    UserList ** datas = new UserList *[counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        datas[i] = new UserList(1);
    }

    ifstream in("AppData/DB_lists");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        datas[i]->read(&in);
    }
    in.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        datas[i]->temp(); // Temp - вывести название списка.
    }

    return;
}
```

МЕТОД ТEMP

```
void UserList::temp()
{
    cout << "\nName is: " << _listName;
    return;
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Писать/читать в файл, наверное, в вашем случае лучше в бинарном режиме (добавить флаг std::ios::binary в конструкторы ofstream/ifstream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

дисклеймер: используйте что-нибудь более высокоуровневое для сериализации/десериализации.

Скорей всего причина в том, что вы сохраняете в файл указатель char* UserList::_listName, вместо данных, на которые он указывает. Пока вы запускали друг за другом запись/чтение, вероятно данные оставались на тех же местах, поэтому выглядело все как будто работает нормально. А после перезапуска там конечно уже был мусор.

Comment: Все верно, причина была в char* UserList::_listName. Заменил на char * _listname[64], и все заработало. Спасибо Вам огромное, @Vladimir Gamalian!

Comment: @DecoYo Надеюсь, что все же на  `char _listname[64]`. Только учтите - если вы добавите хоть одну виртуальную функцию, получите неприятности. Лучше бы вам не использовать запись памяти с адреса `this` - ну нездоровое это занятие!

Comment: Да, ошибся, я заменил на char _listname[64]. Спасибо Вам, пошел учить матчасть)

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что `SetListName` динамически выделяет память для `_listName`, не забывает при этом освобождать предыдущую и т.д.? Тогда я бы делал так (вообще-то еще нужна проверка на нулевой указатель; думаю, допишете сами):

```
void read(ifstream *in)  {
    size_t sz;
    in->read(&sz, sizeof(sz)); 
    char * buf = new char[sz];
    in->read(buf, sz); 
    SetListName(buf);
    delete[] buf;
}

void write(ofstream *out){ 
    size_t sz = strlen(_listName)+1; 
    out->write(&sz, sizeof(sz)); 
    out->write(_listName,sz);
}
```

И, само собой, с файлом работать в бинарном режиме!

На будущее - никогда не пишите просто `this`. Даже наличие одной виртуальной функции, не говоря уж об указателях, делает это неработоспособным...